# ChannelProcessingFilter is not executing first in filter chain in spring security

Tags: java, spring, redirect, web, spring-security

I have following config:

```
<http entry-point-ref="authenticaionEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/custom-url" access="ROLE_USER"
            requires-channel="https" />


Now since url: /custom-url is on https. I am facing a weird use case when user is logged in  (jsessionid is maintained https only, so on http user's session won't be recognized) :

1. Open http://www.dummy-domain.com/custom-url
2. User is redirected to http://www.dummy-domain.com/login
3. User is redirected to https://www.dummy-domain.com/login
4. User is redirected to https://www.dummy-domain.com, since user is already logged in.

In my opinion, it should have been this way :

1. Open http://www.dummy-domain.com/custom-url
2. User is redirected to https://www.dummy-domain.com/custom-url

I am assuming in first scenario channel processing filter is not getting executed first.
```

Any thoughts what I am missing? For info, I am still on spring security 3.1